# phpmailer WHERE query 2 variables

Tags: php, mysql

My phpmailer sends out to users who have a emailstatus of "new"

i want to also make it so it only selects users who have "Active" on there status column.

```
       $emails = mysqli_query($this->dbc, "
                  SELECT
                                         e.`email`,
                                         e.`id`
                  FROM `user` e
                  WHERE e.`emailstatus` = 'new'
                  LIMIT 1000
              ");
```

What is the best way to include another WHERE statement?

```
       $emails = mysqli_query($this->dbc, "
                  SELECT
                                         e.`email`,
                                         e.`id`
                  FROM `user` e
                  WHERE e.`emailstatus` = 'new'
                  WHERE e.'status' = 'Active'
                  LIMIT 1000
              ");
```

I tried adding WHERE e.'status' = 'Active' but this also brings up an error.

Comment: How is this problem related to PHPMailer? You haven't shared any such code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use WHERE clause twice. You can [combine conditions](http://www.hackingwithphp.com/9/3/13/multiple-where-conditions) by using AND or OR clause.

```
$emails = mysqli_query($this->dbc, "
              SELECT
               e.`email`,
               e.`id`
              FROM `user` e
              WHERE e.`emailstatus` = 'new'
              AND e.`status` = 'Active'
              LIMIT 1000
          ")
```

Be also careful, as your line is using ( **'** ) instead of ( **`** )

```
WHERE e.'status' = 'Active' // e.`status` = 'Active'
```